# Given null or empty string when signin with email and password firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to check if email is verified or not, I tried to use AuthStateListener but does not work so I tried to do this-

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
      email =intent.getStringExtra("email");
      password = intent.getStringExtra("password");
 auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirmbtn);
    confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("e",email+""+password);
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).
                    addOnCompleteListener(ConfirmActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                checkIfEmailVerified(email,password);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(ConfirmActivity.this, "failed to sign in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                        }
                    });

        }
    });
```

but return unfortunatily error for first time when click on confirm button at this line

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).
```

exception:

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: iti.signinsignupfirebase, PID: 4108
              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
                  at        com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zzdr(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source)
                  at iti.signinsignupfirebase.ConfirmActivity$1.onClick(ConfirmActivity.java:54)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Please [edit] your question to include them

Comment: The error message is quite explicit: either the email address or the password you provide is empty.

Answer (score 1):

As in firebase current version there is a bug so we need to sign out user for first attempt otherwise  verification  var will always shows false  . here is a trick you can do,  When you register user for first time  send a verification  email to  that user and then sign out that user and show login screen. 
 After that ,if user sign in check for email verification   and if he/she verify then go to main activity.